# Free $R$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I recently learned about free $R$-modules. I saw some non-examples, including $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}[t]/(t^2-1)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[t]$.

Is it true that, in general, $R/I$ is not free for any nontrivial ideal $I$ of $R$?

This seems to be the case, because if $I$ is not trivial, there is some nonzero $x\in I$ such that the equivalence class of $x$ in $R/I$ cannot be written as a unique sum of elements in $R$. (I realise a more precise/careful argument is probably needed). Is this idea correct, or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @rschwieb I mean in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume $R$ is commutative.

The annihilator of a (nonzero) free module is always zero.

The annihilator of $R/I$ is $I$.

Comment: Why do you restrict to commutative rings? The same is clearly true for rings with identity at least.

Comment: How do you know that the annihilator of a free module is zero? My definition of free module $M$ is an $R$-module which admits a basis, i.e. for each $x\in M$, there is a unique finite sum $\sum_x a_x x$, with $a_x\in R$.

Comment: @woofy, and what problem do you have in showing that the annihilator of a free module is zero?

Comment: @MarianoSuarez-Alvarez If there is $r\in Ann_R M -\{0\}$, then for every $x\in M$, $rx=0=\sum_{y\in Y} ra_y y$, where $Y$ is the basis, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here

Comment: If $r$ is in the annihilator of $M$, then $rm=0$ for all $m\in M$. Pick $m$ to be one of the basis elements of $M$: what can you say about $r$ then?